# java convert long to formatted string (less than an hour)

Tags: java, time, long-integer

251786 <-> 00:04:11,786

```
Date date = new Date(251786);
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss,SSS");
String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
```

However, dateFormatted's value is 18:04:11,786

What happens to HH?

Comment: I think your input is wrong `00:04:11,786` actually equals `7740011786` milliseconds since the epoch

Comment: The value is `00:04:11.786 GMT`. The actual printed value depends on your local timezone.

Comment: I have a similar problem. However, I use directly `String.format("%1$tk:%1$tM:%1$tS.%1$tL", time)`, where `time` is a `long` representing a duration in milliseconds. The problem is that I got always 01 hour, the minute, second and millisecond are all correct, and I am pretty sure the duration is less than an hour. My computer has the timezone UTC+01, could this be the reason why I have 01 hour?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for the Date constructor (251786), indicates almost 252 seconds since epoch (or January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). Assuming your machine isn't running in GMT you're getting the local time offset - or January 1, 1970 00:04:11,786 GMT - and I'm guessing you're in GMT-6 (i.e. your timezone is 6 hours behind GMT, so you get 18 in the hours field - or 6 pm).

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)

> Date(long date) 
>             Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Elliott and in addition to that little bit more explanation is here :).

As you're in GMT-6 (6 hours behind GMT) standard `the epoch` will be taken as `January 1, 1970, 18:00:00` rather than `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`

And then what ever the argument(`251786`) you pass to `Date` constructor will be added to `the epoch`. In you case It will be `January 1, 1970, 18:00:00 000` **+** `251786` -> the result you see will be 
`January 1, 1970, 18:04:11 786`.

You can understand it more by trying it out with pattern `EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss,SSS` or even other patterns.

```
Date date = new Date(251786);
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss,SSS");
String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
```

Answer (score -1):

Its absolutely 4 minutes and 11 seconds, that's what it is showing.

Your milliseconds argument need to be increased to get hours.